# How do I load only 10 rows at a time from http post response, let the rest load in the background in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, http

**Http Post Request**

I simply want the table on the front end of my website to display the first 10 rows from my datasource, the rest to be loaded in the background (it's a huge dataset 100000+ rows) and to be able to access the rest of the dataset as and when required. Even possible?

```
 this.http.post(environment.BASE_URL + searchPage, body, { 'headers': headers }).subscribe((selectedUser: any) => {
    
    // the line below gets me the first 10 rows but I also want the next 10 to be
    // available to me should I select this in the front end. Effectively a lazy load.

    this.userlogins = selectedUser.slice(0, 10);

    // End 

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.userlogins);
    
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    })
    if (new MatTableDataSource(this.userlogins).filteredData.length < 1) {
      this.searchData = false;
    }
    console.log(new MatTableDataSource(this.userlogins));
  }, (error: any) => {
    console.error(error);
  })
```

Comment: This would be more determined by the endpoint you're hitting. Does it support pagination/result limiting? If so, then you can load the first 10 initially, and then set up a queue of whatever size you want to load the rest over time.

If the endpoint doesn't let you specify how many records to return though, then no.

Comment: @Cineris no my endpoint doesn't do this currently however I can make it do that. I wasn't aware of the queue interface until you mentioned it. After a cursory glance it's seem to be the way I need to go.